# Align object to the bottom of a header

Tags: html, css, object, alignment

I have successfully stored a PDF object on the resume section of this website I am working on. However, I am trying to align the top of the Object (which in this case is the PDF viewer) with the bottom of the header (which is represented by a gray line in the upcoming screenshot). I keep getting whitespace in between the top of the Object and the bottom of the header, as evidenced in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mjb5H.png).

Here is the HTML of the body section in question:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="index.html" id="logo"> <h1>
        <div id="header_title">
            Title
        </div></h1> </a>
        <div id="header_border"></div>
        <nav id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html" class="selected" >About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="resume.html">Resume</a>
                </li>
                <li class="subNav">
                    <a>Portfolio</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="writing_samples.html">Writing Samples</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="photoshop.html">Photoshop</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <object id="resume" data="img/Resume.pdf" type="application/pdf" style="float: left" width="100%" height="100%">

        <p>
            It appears you don't have a PDF plugin for this browser.
            No biggie... you can <a href="myfile.pdf">click here to
            download the PDF file.</a>
        </p>

    </object>

</body>
```

And CSS:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', open sans;
    height: 100%;

}

#wrapper {
    max-width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 5%;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%; /* images fill width of parent container
     image will shrink with size of container */
}

h3 {
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}

/************************
 HEADING
 *************************/

header {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0; /* top, right, bottom, left */
    padding: 5px 0 0 0; /* ibid */
    width: 100%; /* since floated, this element does not have an
     explicit width; therefore, it must be assigned to 100%
     of page*/

}


#logo {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', open sans;
    /* font-size: 100px; font-size is overruled in responsive.css
                            for computer screens set in min-width 660*/
    margin: 85px 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    /*  font-weight: normal; will unbold the headline, as headlines
     are set to bold by default. */
    line-height: 0.8em;

}

#header_title {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50px;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

#header_border {
    width: calc(95% - 70px);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 50px;

    border-bottom: 2px solid #dddede;
}


/************************
 NAVIGATION
 *************************/

nav {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 0;
}

nav > ul > li { /* only impacts the first list items; keeps About, Portfolio, Contacts in horizontal line*/
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

nav > ul> li> a {
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 15px 10px;
}

nav > ul > li.subNav ul > li> a {
}

nav > ul > li.subNav ul { /* now free to style/block secondary list*/
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: pink;
}

nav ul li.subNav:hover ul {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

/***********************
 * BODY
 */

#resume {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Try `vertical-align: top;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your header styles have a margin of 30px on the bottom. Remove this and the object will line up with the bottom of your header.

```
margin: 0 0 30px 0; /* top, right, bottom, left */
```

should be

```
margin: 0;
```